# Magento 2 - 401 controller in magento admin

Tags: magento2, module, adminhtml, ajax

I currently have a module that adds a field to the admin cms page. I've written a controller and on input change I want to ajax this controller.

This is the simple controller I added to start testing:

```
namespace Vendor\Module\Controller\Adminhtml\Index;

use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;

class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    /**
     * Save action
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        die('Hello world');
    }  

}
```

My Router is located in:

> Vendor\Module\etc\adminhtml\routes.xml

And looks like the following:

```
<router id="admin">
        <route frontName="namehere" id="namehere">
            <module name="Vendor_Module" before="Magento_Backend" />
        </route>
    </router>
```

I've added the following into a block to call in the admin cms page:

```
public function getFormAction()
    {
        return '/admin/namehere/index/index';
    }
```

And when I call this controller via the block in the ajax request or even access the controller I get either redirected to the dashboard with an error of key issue or via the ajax:

> Status Code: 401 Unauthorized

or

> Invalid security or form key. Please refresh the page.

Now I'm logged in as the admin so shouldn't have any permission issues. Why am I getting a 401? I'm pretty stumped. Any help always appreciated.

Comment: Did you create acl.xml under etc/ for your module action? If not please create and re-login to check.

Comment: I did not. What does the acl.xml file need to look like?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For adminarea you should use `\Magento\Backend\App\Action` instead of `\Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action`

```
class Index extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action
```

Comment: thank you! Everyone else was saying to use Framework. Works a treat now.